# Exact threading of async WhenAll

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

If I call an async method multiple times in a loop without awaiting, and save the tasks to a list, which I then feed to the WhenAll in the same method, what is the exact threading story in this scenario?

Say, we're making HTTP requests. The sync part of my methods before the I/O (preparing the requests) will run sequentially on the original thread. The waiting for HTTP calls to complete will happen in parallel for all requests, while the original thread will keep running until it gets to the WhenAll statement. Then (assuming I/O is still pending) the original thread will get released to the thread pool.

My question is, what happens after this? When I/O completes for each of the tasks, what thread(s) will run the remainder of the code inside the async methods (assuming its all regular sync code, e.g. processing the HTTP response)?

1. will continuations run in parallel on their own threads, taken from the thread pool, or
2. will they run one-by-one on one thread? or
3. will the continuations inside the methods run on multiple threads and the continuation after WhenAll run on one thread?

I hope it's option #2 but I want to know for sure.

Comment: They will run on thread pool threads, in parallel if necessary (unless sync context was captured like in UI applications, in which case they all will run on UI thread).

Comment: The methods hand back a `Task` which will be marked as complete when the code has run. The original code that generated that `Task` has no way of *knowing* what you do with those `Tasks`, such as choosing to use multiple of them inside a `WhenAll`, and it's those methods whose implementations decide how code continues to run.

Comment: Thanks @Evk for finding the answered question. I searched but could not phrase it like that.